# Unable to write using fwrite()

Tags: c++, mfc, fwrite

I'm using `fwrite` in an MFC application to print content of `lBuffer` as shown in following C++ code:

```
PvBuffer *lBuffer = NULL;

// Retrieve next buffer     
PvResult lResult = lStream.RetrieveBuffer(&lBuffer, &lOperationResult, 1000);
if (lResult.IsOK())
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\acm45\\Desktop\\abuffer.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(lBuffer, 1, 10075968, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Any idea why the content of the file abuffer.bin is always empty even though `IResult` returns success?
 Note the file is always created when I run the program, but it is empty and size is 0KB.

**Update:**
To debug I did this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\acm45\\Desktop\\abuffer.bin", "wb");
if (fp) {
    fwrite(lBuffer, 1,10075968, fp);
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    printf("error opening file");
}
```

and the output **did not** print "error opening file", but still the file is empty. What do I do now?

Comment: please do not mix up tabs and spaces. better use spaces all the time.

Comment: add `perror` call to the else branch: `else { perror( "fopen" ); }`

Comment: exactly what i suggested but someone down voted my answer :P

Comment: @nav_jan if you *answered* with adding `perror` I understand why it got downvoted, since it doesn't solve the issue (thus, it is not an answer), it just helps with debugging it (thus, it is a comment).

Comment: is this a console application? Have you tried running it under debugger? Does it even finish or maybe it just crashes?

Comment: You failed to isolate the error correctly; if you cannot even make the second code snippet work then there is something wrong with your environment and we cannot help you. FYI this works:
http://pastebin.com/fP8DLyMj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having some undefined behaviour there.

The man page of fwrite says:

> `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`
>
> The function fwrite() writes nmemb elements of data, each size bytes long, to the stream pointed to by stream, obtaining them from the location given by ptr.

But your call

```
lStream.RetrieveBuffer( &lBuffer, &lOperationResult, 1000 );
```

lets me guess you don't have 10075968 elements with each one byte long.

Also: Is your buffer a collection of POD elements? If not, that's another reason for undefined behaviour. `fwrite` is only for POD types.

*Generally*, it is better to use C++ streams.

---

**addendum to explain fwrite**

`size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`

Here, `size` means the size of a *single* element.

`nmemb` is the number of such elements. For example:

```
...
struct Foobar {
    int frob;
};

int main () {
    ...
    Foobar thingies[5];
    fwrite (thingies, sizeof(Foobar), 5, some_file);
}
```

A more generic approach is this:

```
    Foobar thingies[5];
    const size_t nm = sizeof(thingies) / sizeof(Foobar);
    fwrite (thingies, sizeof(Foobar), nm, some_file);
```

This read: "size of the array, divided by size of a single element, which equals the number of elements in that array".

But note that this only works for arrays, not pointers!

```
    Foobar *thingies = new Foobar[5];
    const size_t nm = sizeof(thingies) / sizeof(Foobar);
    fwrite (thingies, sizeof(Foobar), nm, some_file);
    // THIS IS WRONG. sizeof(thingies) now equals to the
    // size of a pointer!
```

Comment: Solved, I actually have 4 elements (found by sizeof(lBuffer)) and I know that each element is 2 bytes long so I did : fwrite(lBuffer, 2, 4, fp); And its printing correctly!

Comment: its camera output:  2448 X 2058 pixels  X 2 bytes each (its actually 12 bit)

Comment: i think I am wrong in my understanding of 3rd parameter in  fwrite(lBuffer, 2, 4, fp); actually lBuffer contains more than 4 elements, and 4 is just the size of the pointer (found from size(Lbuffer)). But even then saw some nos in the file....I am delighted. Though i dont know how to find exact size of this Buffer...

Comment: @gpuguy: I added some examples on how `fwrite` is to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\acm45\\Desktop\\abuffer.bin", "wb");
if (fp) {
    fwrite(lBuffer, 1, 10075968, fp);
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    perror("fopen");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you are retrieving the buffer correctly. Use the function if available in that class to get the size of the buffer and pass it instead of that constant.

Comment: `sizeof(lBuffer)` is probably equal to 4 or 8

Comment: using sizeof(LBuffer) gives 4.

Comment: Thanks,. hmmm, can you tell me how do I know the size of the lBuffer?

Comment: @gpuguy: The documentation for whatever library you're using should say how to find out.